# Starter motor issue

Tags: starter, peugeot

I wondered if anyone could help me with this one. I have today fitted a brand new starter motor to my Peugeot 407 2.0 hdi. The starter is brand new but after fitting I am still getting the old starter spinning but not engaging issue. Does anyone know what this could be? It is driving me nuts and can’t seem to sort this one. Have tested that the starter is functioning ok but once fitted it just spins and does not engage. Have i done something wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did the problem start suddenly with the old starter motor, or did it get worse over a period of time?

Comment: The old starter begin grinding a little over about a week or so and would occasionally just spin in it’s own making that hideous noise but then would start in second attempt. Now  I have fitted new one it just spins on its own all the time so am really baffled by it all.

Comment: Have you looked at the starter while cranking to make sure you're getting good engagement. Does the car ever start, or does the starter not spin always?

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on your comment is that the teeth on the flywheel have been damaged, so fitting a new starter will exhibit the same fault.  You need to check the teeth on the flywheel by looking/feeling them through the starter motor aperture.

You could try rotating the engine a little to see if the starter then meshes with good teeth on the flywheel.  If the engine then starts then you can be pretty sure the teeth are damaged in sole locations.

Comment: Thank you for you help with this, very much appreciated. I will take alook at the teeth on the flywheel today and see if there is a problem there. One thing I did think of late last night which I should have checked really is the fuses. Could one of those have possibly blown?

Comment: If the starter is spinning, I can’t imagine that there could be a blown fuse.  I would first try turning the engine a little with a spanner, or if it is a manual transmission you could rock the car a little in gear to move the engine.

Comment: I checked the teeth on the flywheel today and they look fine to me. The fuses are also all fine so I am wandering now if the starter is the correct one for my car.  I got the starter from carspares. They simply ask for the vehicle reg and go get the part from out the back. It looked identical but was a different make tot he original which was a Mitsubishi. Not sure if that would be the cause of the problem or not but I am out of ideas now. I may have to get it investigated at the garage.

Comment: @Phil The main 12v cable is has a good connection?  Also verify that the engine earth strap is connected well.

Comment: I have just been out and checked all the connections again and all seems spot on. I am getting 12v at the trigger and can hear the motor spinning when the wife attempts to start the car. Not sure about the engine earth strap though? Is there an additional earth to consider here? Once again thanks for your time and help with this very much appreciated my friend.

Comment: There should be at least 1 thick wire/braiding going from the engine to the body somewhere.  If this is damaged it may have too high a resistance.

Comment: When you tested the starter off the car, did the pinion move out as expected as if moving toward the flywheel?